# Calcular a média aritmética dos números inteiros entre 15 (inclusive) e 100 (inclusive)

Tags: python, matemática, lógica

Preciso calcular a média aritmética dos números inteiros entre 15 (inclusive) e 100 (inclusive). Fiz este código:

```
x=0
for i in range(15,101):
    x=x+i
    print('%d / %d = %5.1f' % (x,i,x/i))
```

Se for a média geral seria um pouquinho diferente:

```
x=0
for i in range(15,101):
   x=x+1
   media=x/85
   print('media geral é %5.2f'%(media))
```

Bom até tenho ciência sobre os códigos de `while` e `for`, todavia não entendi o que a questão realmente quer. Acho que a questão foi muito subjetiva, não entendi se quer o valor da média final de [15,100] ou a média de n+1/n.

Answer (score 2):

bom a media aritmética é a soma dos intervalos no caso todos os valores contidos entre 15 e 100 divido pelo quantidade do intervalos, seu exemplo está erado pois vc divide a cada numero pela media o que nao está pedido no seu caso ficaria:

```
soma=0
valor_intervalo=len(range(15,101))

for i in range(15,101):
   soma+=i
media=soma/valor_intervalo

print("media geral {}".format(media))
```

Answer (score 1):

"*Números inteiros entre 15 (inclusive) e 100 (inclusive)*" quer dizer que são todos os números desta lista: 15, 16, 17, 18... até o 100.

["*Média aritmética*"](https://www.mundovestibular.com.br/articles/60/1/MEDIA-ARITMETICA/Paacutegina1.html) de um conjunto de números é simplesmente a soma desses números dividido pela quantidade de números.

Por exemplo, se fosse "média aritmética dos números inteiros entre 2 (inclusive) e 4 (inclusive)", seria a média aritmética de (2, 3, 4), que seria a soma deles (2 + 3 + 4 = 9) dividido pela quantidade de números (3), então a média seria 9 / 3 = 3.

No seu caso, os números são (15, 16, 17, .... , 99, 100) e a quantidade de números é 86 (sim, pode contar, não são 85).

De qualquer forma, para fazer isso em Python, você pode usar um [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) de 15 a 101 (já que um `range` inclui o primeiro número, mas não inclui o último).

Em seguida pode usar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) para calcular a soma dos números, e [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para obter a quantidade de números, e aí é só dividir um pelo outro:

```
numeros = range(15, 101)
media = sum(numeros) / len(numeros)
print(media) # 57.5
```

Com isso você obtém a média, que é 57,5.

---

Mas como isso é um exercício, acredito que a intenção é que você use laços como o `for` ou `while`, então você pode fazer isso "manualmente" (apesar da solução acima ser bem mais sucinta e simples):

```
soma = 0
quantidade = 0
for i in range(15, 101):
    soma += i
    quantidade += 1

media = soma / quantidade
print(media)
```

Ou ainda sem usar o `range`:

```
soma = 0
quantidade = 0
i = 15
while i <= 100:
    soma += i
    quantidade += 1
    i += 1

media = soma / quantidade
print(media)
```

Repare que eu só calculo a média no final (depois do `for`/`while`), pois só depois do *loop* é que eu tenho a soma e a quantidade de números.

Comment: Muito legal, porém a conversão em lista é desnecessária - tanto `sum()` quanto `len()` trabalham com os objetos do tipo `range` de forma mais eficiente sem precisar "*materializar*" a lista.

Comment: @nosklo Tinha esquecido desse detalhe. Atualizei a resposta, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

A `média aritmética` de uma sequencia de valores corresponde ao `quociente` entre a `soma dos valores` e a `quantidade dos valores`. Em outras palavra, a média aritmética é o resultado da divisão entre a `soma dos valores` pela `quantidade de valores`.

para resolver esta questão podemos implementar o seguinte código abaixo...

```
def media(r):
    cont = soma = 0
    for i in r:
        cont += 1
        soma += i
    return soma / cont


if __name__ == '__main__':
    resultado = media(range(15, 101))

    print(f'{resultado:.2f}')
```

Observe que este código foi montado a partir de uma função `def`, a partir da qual é obtido tanto a soma dos valores quanto a quantidade de valores para, em seguida, calcular a média aritmética. E, por último, o referido resultado é exibido com duas casas decimais.